# Ruby on rails convention for naming date/time fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, coding-style, naming-conventions

I want to make a scaffold like this:

```
rails generate scaffold Job started_at:datetime completed_at:datetime price:decimal paid_at:datetime estimated_completion_at:datetime comment:text
```

I've added "_at" to the datetime fields because that seemed to be the convention as rails timestamp fields are either "_at" for datetime or "_on" for date. But is this actually a convention? Is it OK if I just have "paid" instead of "paid_at" and "completed" instead of "completed_at"?

I really want to get this right from the start. I've been programming in c# for years but I'm new to ruby on rails. I like all the conventions and I want to make sure I'm doing this the proper 'rails way'.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I don't know of any specific rails convention, and it doesn't really matter since there's nothing in rails that keys off of datetime fields. The convention I've always gone with is suffix datetime columns with `_at` and date columns with `_on`. It always seemed more natural to say on a day and at a time.

Comment: It doesn't break anything if you don't follow it, but that's the naming convention.

Comment: I agree with this convention as they pretty clearly indicate a time/datetime versus plain date. Having a field like Employee.hired_at sounds ridiculous versus Employee.hired_on sounds perfect. As with many things, it doesn't much matter what you do as long as you're consistent.

Answer (score 14):

How you name your date and time columns is not an officially stated convention and does not affect the way your code works. However, if you want to go »the Rails way« you should probably follow conventions generally accepted in the rails community.

- First of all, there is a [a community-driven Ruby on Rails style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/rails-style-guide#models), but it doesn't contain any date column naming conventions.
- One hint are the Active Record timestamp columns, like `created_at` as @sierrasdetandil noted in their answer.
- Another way to figure out what some conventions are is by looking at the Rails style guides of popular Rails shops. For example thoughtbot [state in their style guide](https://github.com/thoughtbot/guides/tree/master/style/rails):

> - Name date columns with `_on` suffixes.
> - Name datetime columns with `_at` suffixes.
> - Name time columns (referring to a time of day with no date) with `_time` suffixes.

This will help you find good names for your columns and prevent confusion for other developers. I think this is a good convention to follow, and you might too, as long as you don't have a compelling reason to name your columns differently.

Answer (score 5):

Actually, there *is* a convention in Rails for the names of two specific timestamp columns: `created_at` and `updated_at` have special behaviors. From 
[Active Record Basics — Ruby on Rails Guides; 2.2 Schema Conventions](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions)

> There are also some optional column names that will add additional features to Active Record instances:
>
> - `created_at` - Automatically gets set to the current date and time when the record is first created.
> - `updated_at` - Automatically gets set to the current date and time whenever the record is updated.
> - ...

There is no mention in that page of column names ending in "_on".

Answer (score 1):

It probably is not a convention in Rails but it actually makes sense to append `_at` at the end of date/datetime columns.  Compared to just `paid`, `paid_at` gives you the notion that you are working with a date/datetime object whereas `paid` can also be a boolean or a string that explains the status of the payment. So I guess this isn't limited to just Rails.

Comment: I'm having this discussion at work at the moment. (About a json structure btw, but that is irrelevant imho). Reason was indeed that existing date attribute names had a boolean connotation to them. Fair enough, I'm all for self documenting code and in case an attribute name is ambiguous there is room for improvement.
The suggestion was to use the suffix At, but to me this brings also ambiguity along with it. At can both mean a moment in time and a (physical) location.
In your case paid_at could also refer to a location (cash register, self service checkout, ...).
I prefer _date as suffix.

Comment: I think it really depends on your convention and standards in the company.  `paid_date` can be just a date data type while `paid_at` can be a timestamp like how `created_at` and `updated_at` are set up in Rails.  For location, I'd personally go with `paid_location`

Comment: I agree that standards and conventions are important and in case of Ruby I agree to stick with the standards. However what if you need to define standards/conventions? I argue that the `at` suffix is ambiguous as it can refer to a location or a moment in time. So your suggestion to use `location` and `date` to refer to them respectively feels like a better choice.